# PokeAPI & Flask: Combining different properties on API

Tags: python-3.x, api, flask-restful

API beginner here,

I'm creating an API that calls both a character name and their description with one ENDPOINT. So far I have the data appearing at separate endpoints.

Goal: Getting output format ('http://127.0.0.1:5000/v1/pokemon/string:name') to look similar to this:

{ "name": "pichu", "description": "It is not yet skilled at storing electricity.It may send out a jolt if amused or startled."}

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, Response
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, fields, marshal_with
import requests, json

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

# Prints all Pokemon via JSON
@app.route('/v1/pokemon/all', methods=['GET'])
def poke_names():
    data = []
    name_url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151"
    while True:
        resp = requests.get(name_url)
        json = resp.json()
        data.extend(json.get('results', []))
        name_url = json.get('next')
        if not name_url: break
    return jsonify(data)


@app.route('/v1/pokemon/<string:name>/title', methods=['GET'])
def get_poke(name):
     return jsonify({'name': name})


#flavor Text ie pokemon description
@app.route('/v1/pokemon/<int:pokemon_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_description(pokemon_id):
    descrip_url = f"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/{pokemon_id}"
    r = requests.get(descrip_url)
    json_blob = r.json()
    flav_text = extract_descriptive_text(json_blob)
    return jsonify({'description': flav_text})


def extract_descriptive_text(json_blob, language='en'):
    text = []
    for f in json_blob['flavor_text_entries']:
        if f['language']['name'] == language:
            text.append(f['flavor_text'])
    return text


#error occurs below
@app.route('/v1/pokemon/<string:name>')
def all_poke_data(name, flav_text):
    return jsonify({'name':name, 'description':flav_text})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Error: When I try to combine them I get

```
TypeError: all_poke_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'flav_text'
```

Thank you for any pointers provided!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

Just add this function, which is a combination of both route functions

```
@app.route('/v1/pokemon/<string:name>')
def get_poke(name):
    descrip_url = f"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/{name}"
    r = requests.get(descrip_url)
    json_blob = r.json()
    flav_text = extract_descriptive_text(json_blob)
    return jsonify({'name': name},{'description': flav_text})
```